# QGIS Flatpak installation 'ModuleNotFoundError' under Linux Mint

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, linux-mint, modulenotfounderror

I'm pretty new to Linux and trying to install QGIS with some extra plugins for hydrodynamic modelling.

I followed the instructions regarding the flatpak installation on qgis.org. After installing the Plugin I wanted, I ran into 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'.

I already tried to add the module the way mentioned on qgis.org by

> `flatpak run --devel --command=pip3 org.qgis.qgis install matplotlib --user`

and got a runtime error:

> error: runtime/org.kde.Sdk/x86_64/5.15-22.08 not installed

installed the required runtime via flatpak and installed matplotlib successfully. Anyhow, I received a warning:

> WARNING: The scripts fonttools, pyftmerge, pyftsubset and ttx are
> installed in '/home/hymo/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.   Consider
> adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this
> warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Afterwards, I started QGIS again but still received the error regarding the module matplotlib. In the QGIS python console I tried `import matplotlib` but also received the error.

I also tried adding further paths to the Environment in QGIS, but nothing helped.
[image]

Do I have to tweak the PATH or PYTHONPATH in any way so QGIS looks in the Mint's Python?